# How to downgrade Wamp MySQL version?

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I am having a problem in downgrading the MySQL version in WAMP. Currently I am using 5.6.12 and I need to downgrade it it 5.5. But before I can download the old version. By choosing 'get more...' option and it leads me to the MySQL add-on. But the website looks different. It only shows the WampServer installation. I can't find the MySQL add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should ask this in superuser.com, but you may check this one at:

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/

I think now they are providing an already-packaged `mysql` in a single wamp-installer..
So, just try to download the older version..
WampServer version 2.2 has MySQL 5.5.24..
hope this helps..

Answer (score 21):

It is now possible to install the multi MySql versions with executables provided by the wamp team.

Here's what you want to do:

- First, make sure you have Wampserver 3.0.9 (or newer) installed on your machine. 
  As of the time I'm writing this, it is not possible to download this version directly from the wampserver official homepage. You have to download and install 3.0.6 from wampserver.com and then update to 3.0.9. You can find the update installer [here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) .
- Then you can install Wampserver addons from source forge.
  In your case, you just have to [pick the version of MySql that you want](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Addons/Mysql/) and to install it.
- Finally, restart wamp and then you will be allowed to pick the version  of MySql that you want from the wamp option box pinned on the bottom right of your windows task bar.

Hope it helps someone !

Comment: Thanks! I installed the update and now my wampserver is version 3.1.1 and  MySQL defaulted to `5.7.14` and it seems to be working fine so far

Comment: This worked for me to get MySQL 5.5 installed on WampServer Version 3.2.3

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it.

1 - download the version of mysql that you want to install.

2 - Copy / Paste it in your folder **C:\wamp\bin\mysql**

3 - **Close** and **run** Wamp server again

4 - Left click the Wamp icon in your taskbar then **Mysql > Version > 'select your version'**

*Example mysql folder name :* "mysql5.6.17"

Note: If you copy the version from an existing server with database on it, the database would be copied as well.

Answer (score 1):

here is what i did :
(I have wamp 3)

1. install wamp 2.2 (dont have to remove current version)
2. go to  C:\wamp\bin\mysql
3. copy sql5.5.24 folder and paste it in C:\wamp64\bin\mysql(wamp 3 folder)
4. remove wamp 2.2
5. restart wamp
6. click on wamp icon in right corner ot taskbar ,select MySQL --> version and there it is

cheers :)