# WordPress MySql incompatibility. Locally developed version : 5.6.17 & hosting providers version 5.5.36

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wamp, incompatibility

I developed a wordpress site locally using WAMP with MySQL ver. 5.6.17.
While trying to take the website live (using the Duplicator wp plugin), I am not able to as I got an error for version incompatibility.

The shared hosting that i have purchased to take the site live cant upgrade the MySql version from 5.5.36 to 5.6.n.

Is there something I can do now with the wp site locally developed to take it live? looking for any possible solutions...

Comment: You should be able to downgrade your version of MySQL on WAMP - there is an existing Stackoverflow post here to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819609/how-to-downgrade-wamp-mysql-version

Comment: Please consider making an [edit] to your question to tell us the error you got.   You can also look for a hosting provider with more up-to-date server software.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicator has a mode where it uses `mysqldump` to write out your database contents when preparing the package for duplication.  That mode is enabled on Duplicator's settings page. If you write your package with that tool you may, or may not, be able to persuade your cheap and nasty hosting service to import it.

Comment: I just tried the mysqldump mode. It still didn't work. I get this error:
`Deploy Errors: (3809)`
Clicking to see details shows this:
`Unknown collation: The MySQL Version is too old see: What is Compatibility mode & 'Unknown collation' errors? `

And this is the error log: [link]https://web.archive.org/web/20161224150434/http://provilac.com/wordpress/installer-log.txt[link]